# "Have good weekends" vs "Have a good weekend"

Tags: differences, grammatical-number, greetings

As a co-worker walked past me and my team mates this afternoon, he said "Bye. Have good weekends" - by which he meant that he wished each of us to have a good weekend.

Was this grammatically accurate and valid greeting in English? If not, what would be a better way to convey his message?

Comment: It's certainly not standard but I don't see anything incorrect with it. Would you still have an issue with it if he'd said "I hope you all have good weekends"? It's also worth noting that spoken English is often much more flexible.

Comment: 'Have a good weekend, everybody' is grammatical, idiomatic, and would be taken as meaning individually unless context determined otherwise.

Comment: There's only one weekend involved--the one that's about to start.  Stick with the singular.

Comment: The grammar is slightly askew yet correct; nevertheless. your co-worker tries too hard. I bet he's not fun at parties.

Comment: Do you consider '[the] weekend' to be a period of time (which we all share), or an activity ('[your] weekend')?

Comment: The question has been edited, to the detriment of my original meaning. The question, which I should have stated more clearly, was whether there is anything grammatically wrong with the ambiguity of this statement (he could have been wishing us several good weekends, or several good experiences of one weekend...)

Comment: How would he have dealt with *Happy Christmas*?  *Have happy Christmases* or *Have a happy Christmas, everyone*? The latter would be the usual idiomatic form.

Comment: If two people both had their birthdays on the same day it would be correct to tell them "Enjoy your birthdays!" I've also heard "Enjoy your days off!" when both were taking the same day off (but not spending them together). Convention suggests "Enjoy your weekend!" but it's only convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Was this grammatically accurate and valid greeting in English? If not,
>   what would be a better way to convey his message?

Technically "Bye. Have good weekends" is correct in that he is wishing each individual a good weekend, using the collective noun for all of your weekends.  However, colloquially this strikes me as lazy grammar.  Expansions would be more like:

- Bye, I hope each of you has a good weekend
- Bye, I hope you all have a good weekend

The reason I would use the longer version is that it is more personal to each team member, the blanket "have good weekends" feels like more of a throw away comment such as "bye, I'm off".

> is anything grammatically wrong with the ambiguity of this statement

No one would refer to "several good weekends" in this context and so I would not say this is ambiguous, it is clear he is referring to a group of people who each will experience a weekend. There is nothing particularly wrong with the statement, it is just lazy.

Comment: I agree that it's a bit lazy, but it's also **humorous**, specifically because it's  bad grammar, I think:  it's like saying "I know how to say this more properly, but I'm saying it this shorter way to make a bit of a joke".

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your definition o "weekend". The time allotted between Friday at the end of work to Monday start of work is technically correct.

However, when you come back to work on Monday, a frequently asked question is, "How was your weekend?" That indicates each person has a different weekend, even though everyone shared the same time span.

I would say, personally, "weekend" because I recognize it hasn't happened, yet, so currently the individual weekends of each person have not occurred, yet.

If several people told me of their plans for the weekend, their weekends exist, if only in the idea stage. In this case, I would say, "weekends".

Comment: It should be acknowledged that this is an elaboration of the point that was succinctly made by AmI in a comment, above: 'Do you consider '[the] weekend' to be a period of time (which we all share), or an activity ('[your] weekend')?'

Answer (score 0):

"If several people told me of their plans for the weekend, their weekends exist, if only in the idea stage. In this case, I would say, "weekends"."

In your statement above, you wrote "their weekends" referencing plural weekends because there are multiple people, each with a weekend. Why wouldn't you say "their weekend exists" if you believed the statement you made was correct. If I saw a group if people standing around after the weekend, I would definitely say "how were your weekends?". Hence, I believe, "Have good weekends" when addressing a group is the better choice than "have a good weekend"... but then, I guess I'm not fun at parties :o).

Comment: "Have a good weekend, everybody!" clearly addresses all the group and still sounds natural.